# how to select row with max value, while excluding the newest added row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with user ids and the total spend for every order the user has placed. I need to find the highest total spend for every order excluding their latest order. 
I'm not sure how to drop their last order without purchase dates-  the table is in ascending order so the last row would be the latest purchase.

```
user_id      total_spend
1            234
2            123
3            56
1            453
5            560
1            232
2            345
3            210

ideal output 
user_id  total_spend
1        453
2        123
3        56


select user_id, max(total_spend) 
from t
group by user_id
```

does anyone have any ideas of how to solve this?

Comment: Tables don't remember row order. You need to order by a specific column, like `order_date`.

Comment: hi Purple, how can you be sure that your select is always in the chronological order?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an extra column such as id of integer type,which determines the row adding order, and starting from upside with 1 and incrementing by 1 upto 8th row in your illustration, then you can use this query :

```
select t1.user_id, max(t1.total_spend)
  from tab t1
  join
  (
   select max(id) as id, user_id
     from tab 
    group by user_id ) t2
    on t1.id < t2.id 
   and t1.user_id = t2.user_id
 group by t1.user_id;
```

which filters out the latest id columns first, and then gets maximum total spend money grouped by the rest of user ids.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f60094c5c9bc3c1588bc71f767341d30)</kbd>